# python: inherited from builtin type list, how to access elements within new class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, built-in

I wanted to reuse some functionality from the builtin `list()` type, and therefore created a new class inherited from it. Now I would like to access the items of the list. But how?

I could create a class that contains a list internally which I then could work on; but I would very much prefer not to rewrite all the magic functions to mimic the list behavior.

```
class NamedList(list):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        super(NamedList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def tell_me(self):
        print self.name
        print 'all I contain is' 
        for item in ???: #what belongs here?
            print item
```

Comment: oh my. This is why python is beautiful... it is even more easy than expected. If you make this an answer, we can close this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclasses of `list` and other built-in iterable types are iterable.

Just use `self`:

```
def tell_me(self):
    print self.name
    print 'all I contain is' 
    for item in self:
        print item
```